# Issue with getting my button codes to redirect users to another page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

I am having trouble with my code. I am using SharePoint 2013 and am trying to implement codes to get my buttons to redirect a user to another page. However, the buttons do not seem to function. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Is it the code?

Example of the button codes:

```
<input id="btnSearch" onclick="return RedirectUrl();" type="button" value="Carian"/>  
 <input id="btnHome" onclick="return RedirectUrl(/itasset/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/it_list/AllItems.aspx);" type="button" value="home"/>
```

Example of the page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egW44.png)

Comment: why not use a `<a href="" ... >` link ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a javascript function that redirects you to the new page. That function expects a variable as a string, so put the url between single quotes.

Try this:

```js
RedirectUrl('/itasset/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/it_list/AllItems.aspx')
```

And ofcourse `RedirectUrl()` has no variable so it won't work.

Comment: Sorry. I tried it, but it keeps redirecting me to the same page (i.e. the page where the code is)

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/d2q3ubsz/

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you to those who answered. i found another code which worked for me and am sharing it here: <input id="btnHome" onclick="window.location.href='/itasset/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/home_page.aspx'" type="button" value="Return"/>